# MySQL Redo log slower than Buffer pool

Tags: mysql, undo-redo

I have a question to ask friend about MySQL.

Whether the redo log buffer is persisted to disks more slowly than the buffer pool?

When the transaction is not committed, the system gose down, Is it possible that the events in the redo log buffer are not persisted yet? but the dirty pages in the buffer poll are already persisted to disk.

I did not find the relevant documentation, please forgive me for being a novice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB is designed to favor COMMIT over ROLLBACK.  That is, when a transaction finishes, there is very little more to do if you are COMMITting.  But a lot to do if you are ROLLBACKing.

Rollback must undo all the inserts/deletes/updates that were optimistically performed and essentially completed.

For COMMIT, the redo log is eventually thrown away.  For ROLLBACK it is read and actions are taken based on what is in the log.

Also, note that an UPDATE or DELETE of a million rows generates a lot of redo log entries, hence will take a really long time to undo.  Perhaps we should discuss what query you were ROLLBACKing.  There may be a more efficient way to design the data flow.

Another thing to note is that *all* changes to the data and indexes happen in the buffer_pool.  If the big query needed to change so much that it overflowed the buffer_pool, those dumped blocks will need to be reloaded to undo.